# Sort Google spreadsheet multiple columns according to another column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a range of multiple colums from A to F and I would like to arrange these columns to match the order of A-F to column I with F as the matching data reference.

I am able to match column by column but how to sort with a range of columns with non-matching data?

Sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13WP9gS6NijqnPGR8aCzlnCePhBjbh9d4I0xUpL-dxzY/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=sort(A2:F238,xmatch(F2:F238,I2:I),1)
```

[image]